# getting error using timeselavg in Climate Data Operator

Tags: matlab, netcdf, netcdf4, cdo-climate

I am changing my daily data Netcdf file to decade data with [CDO](https://code.mpimet.mpg.de/projects/cdo/) in matlab with command like this

```
cdo timselavg,10 -seldate,2005-05-21,2005-05-31 sst_indonesia_80_18v2.nc 20050503.nc
```

but I get an error like this

```
Assertion failed: offset >= 0, file posixio.c, line 414
```

Any suggestion to solve this problem?

Comment: Given the lack of answers here; perhaps try the [CDO forum](https://code.mpimet.mpg.de/projects/cdo/boards)...

Comment: lack of answers because the wrong CDO tag was used, tag wikis exists for a reason ;-) ...  to start, have you checked the file is ok with ncdump and ncview?  Is the file very large?  Also, have you tried with output format set to nc4?  cdo -f nc4